# Can this be an alternative to singleton pattern?if not why?

Tags: singleton

```
public partial class HelloWorldService : System.Web.UI.Page

    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //HttpHelloWorldService.GetInstance().Execute(Request, Response);

            //--can the above code be written in the following 3 lines??.......

            HttpHelloWorldService.GetInstance();
            HttpHelloWorldService hhtt = new HttpHelloWorldService();
            hhtt.Execute(Request,Response);
        }
    }
```

Note:
-`HttpHelloWorldService` is a static class with 2 methods as followings:

-`public static HttpHelloWorldService GetInstance()`

-`public void Execute(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)`

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed code doesn't make sense. `GetInstance()` is supposed to return an instance, right? Yet you ignore its return value.

```
HttpHelloWorldService.GetInstance();
```

And on the next line you create another instance of this class via constructor.

```
HttpHelloWorldService hhtt = new HttpHelloWorldService();
hhtt.Execute(Request,Response);
```

Are you sure you know what a singleton is? Because this doesn't look like one at all.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No. If this WAS a real singleton implementation you could not successfully call `new` at all. If you can call it, you may can replace the code, but then it is definitely no singleton.

The basic idea of singleton is that you only can create one **single** object of the class. A method like `getInstance()` ist used to return this object if it was created before or create it insight this method. You should **not** be able to create an object on your own by using `new`. The constructor of a singleton class should be private. Otherwies you could create **multiple** objects, what would be against the pattern idea. Use only the return value of `getInstance()` to access the singleton object.

A good description of best practice in singleton pattern is given [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/singleton-design-pattern-%E2%80%93)